# Copy table without copying data

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE foo SELECT * FROM bar
```

copies the table `foo` and duplicates it as a new table called `bar`.

How can I copy the schema of `foo` to a new table called `bar` **without** copying over the data as well?

Comment: how to do the same in sqlserver 2005?

Comment: what means from bar ?

Comment: @SmitSaraiya, [`foo` and `bar` are arbitrary meaningless variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868904/what-is-the-origin-of-foo-and-bar), much like [Alice and Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob).

Comment: @Thunder looks like you can do a "Colums only" copy in MS SQL. See this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505728/create-table-structure-from-existing-table

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE foo SELECT * FROM bar LIMIT 0
```

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE foo SELECT * FROM bar WHERE 1=0
```

Comment: how to do the same in sqlserver 2005?

Comment: @Thunder: Try `select * into foo from bar where 1=0`

Comment: If table bar has triggers associated with it, do you know if those come along as well?

Comment: This does not seem to copy the constraints or keys

Comment: @TimoHuovinen: Perhaps [`create table NewTable like OldTable`](http://blog.sarathonline.com/2011/06/mysql-copying-table-structures.html) is an option for you.  Link copied from deleted answer.

Comment: Be *really* careful about using this under load and at high concurrency. I've just been burned using this at scale, where we created about 50 different tables based off the same source table, at the same time as inserting into the source table from other processes. Basically caused a massive lock meltdown and had to restart MySQL.

Comment: Uhm, OP is confused? This is blatantly a wrong answer to the question, if we pay attention to the title and the emphasis in the question "... **without** copying over the data..." RCNell's answer is rightfully highest voted. Not sure why this one got accepted. Just sayin'.

Comment: It's ONLY for copying Column Names and Column Types. Without any additional data.

Comment: Why not simply `CREATE TABLE foo SELECT * FROM bar WHERE FALSE` ?

Comment: Isn't advisable to avoid using the CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement?  https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/01/10/why-avoid-create-table-as-select-statement/  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-gtids-restrictions.html

Answer (score 524):

Try

```
CREATE TABLE foo LIKE bar;
```

so the keys and indexes are copied over as, well.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)

Comment: This is a better answer since this copies indexes as well!

Comment: It is much better, but still doesn't copy foreign keys.

Comment: @RCNeil, Does `CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;` copies privileges as well? Or must those be copied manually?

Comment: Why has this not been marked as the correct answer?

Comment: Probably because this answer came 4years later than the one marked as correct

Comment: RCNeil, as a non concerned : additions to your answer were rather useful.
A good practice is to put the documentation, rather than just a link.
So I don't clearly see why you was seemingly upset and reverted...

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierVares The documentation text is not directly relevant to the actual answer. The answer text is concise in showing how to do what the question asked, while the documentation link merely provides additional context. As such, bloating the answer with text from the documentation is not helpful.

Comment: thank you! just used your solution to copy a table structure and it worked just fine :D

Answer (score 34):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE bar;
```

you will get a create statement for that table, edit the table name, or anything else you like, and then execute it.

This will allow you to copy the indexes and also manually tweak the table creation.

You can also run the query within a program.

Comment: How could you convert `show create table bar` into a dynamically executable statement?

Comment: the result given by `show create table bar` is already executable, if the script has the permission to create tables, you could parse it and then execute alter table statements too.

Comment: `create table...` will not copy indexes. this answer is the better option

Answer (score 2):

Only want to clone the structure of table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo SELECT * FROM bar WHERE 1 = 2;
```

Also wants to copy the data:

```
CREATE TABLE foo as SELECT * FROM bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

I´d extend the answer to

CREATE TABLE DB.TABLE_copy LIKE DB.TABLE;

depending on the case, you could be more explicit to avoid any mistake.
Thanks RCNeil.