# Create table (structure) from existing table

Tags: sql-server

How to create new table which structure should be same as another table

I tried

```
CREATE TABLE dom AS SELECT * FROM dom1 WHERE 1=2
```

but its not working error occurred

Comment: very helpful, intriguing to have a where clause that is always false!

Comment: this worked in sqlite.. others did not work

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Try:

```
Select * Into <DestinationTableName> From <SourceTableName> Where 1 = 2
```

Note that this will not copy indexes, keys, etc.

If you want to copy the **entire** structure, you need to generate a Create Script of the table. You can use that script to create a new table with the same structure. You can then also dump the data into the new table if you need to.

If you are using Enterprise Manager, just right-click the table and select copy to generate a Create Script.

Comment: Kevin, just a small formatting change in your answer:-

Select * Into <DestinationTableName> From <SourceTableName> Where 1 = 2

Comment: Qutbuddin, 1=2 will prevent data copying from source to destination table. Try yourself:- CREATE TABLE Table1 ( Id int , Name varchar(200) ) INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,'A') INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(2,'B') -- Will create table2 with data in table1 SELECT * INTO Table2 FROM Table1 WHERE 1=2 -- Will create table2 without data in table1 SELECT * INTO Table2 FROM Table1 WHERE 1=2

Comment: I thought 1=2 would be just a weird wrong argument in order to avoid copying data.

Comment: also possible `select top 0 * into dest_table from src_table`

Comment: this query would still copy over the restrictions for columns, like "identity"

Answer (score 75):

This is what I use to clone a table structure (columns only)...

```
SELECT TOP 0 *
INTO NewTable
FROM TableStructureIWishToClone
```

Comment: This solution is clearer than having the extra condition "1 = 2", I would recommend this

Comment: @AbhishekMittal this question is tagged as SQL Server and works fine for me. Are you using some other SQL?

Answer (score 51):

Copy structure only (copy all the columns)

```
Select Top 0 * into NewTable from OldTable
```

Copy structure only (copy some columns)

```
Select Top 0 Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 into NewTable from OldTable
```

Copy structure with data

```
Select * into NewTable from OldTable
```

If you already have a table with same structure and you just want to copy data then use this

```
Insert into NewTable Select * from OldTable
```

Comment: Worked for me in MSSQL 2008 R2

Comment: Great solution, simple and elegant. Is there a hack to make this copy indexes and primary keys as well?

Comment: is it a shallow copy or a deep copy

Comment: Thank you!! I like how you provided options.  Very helpful!

Answer (score 33):

**FOR MYSQL:**

You can use:

```
CREATE TABLE foo LIKE bar;
```

[Documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html).

Comment: The question is tagged as `sql-server` for which this syntax isn't valid, fyi.

Comment: Shouldn't count as answer due to relation to MySQL not to sql-server

Comment: FYI - this also keeps primary keys and indexes, retained.

Answer (score 17):

```
Create table abc select * from def limit 0;
```

This will definite work

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: Notice that the question is tagged with `sql-server`, and this does **not** work in SQL Server.

Answer (score 12):

Its probably also worth mentioning that you can do the following:

Right click the table you want to duplicate **>** Script Table As **>** Create To **>** New Query Editor Window

Then, where is says the name of the table you just right clicked in the script that has been generated, change the name to what ever you want your new table to be called and click `Execute`

Comment: This works well and creates all the constraints etc.

Answer (score 7):

I use the following stored proc for copying a table's schema, including PK, indexes, partition status.  It's not very swift, but seems to do the job.  I I welcome any ideas how to speed it up:

```
    /*
        Clones a table's schema from an existing table (without data)
        if target table exists, it will be dropped first.
        The following schema elements are cloned:
            * Structure
            * Primary key
            * Indexes
            * Constraints
    DOES NOT copy:
        * Triggers
        * File groups

    ASSUMPTION: constraints are uniquely named with the table name, so that we dont end up with duplicate constraint names
*/
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCloneTableStructure]

@SourceTable            nvarchar(255),
@DestinationTable       nvarchar(255),
@PartionField           nvarchar(255),
@SourceSchema           nvarchar(255) = 'dbo',  
@DestinationSchema      nvarchar(255) = 'dbo',    
@RecreateIfExists       bit = 1

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @msg  nvarchar(200), @PartionScript nvarchar(255), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    IF EXISTS(Select s.name As SchemaName, t.name As TableName
                        From sys.tables t
                        Inner Join sys.schemas s On t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                        Inner Join sys.partitions p on p.object_id = t.object_id
                        Where p.index_id In (0, 1) and t.name = @SourceTable
                        Group By s.name, t.name
                        Having Count(*) > 1)

        SET @PartionScript = ' ON [PS_PartitionByCompanyId]([' + @PartionField + '])'
    else
        SET @PartionScript = ''

SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY   
    SET @msg ='  CloneTable  ' + @DestinationTable + ' - Step 1, Drop table if exists. Timestamp: '  + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108)
     RAISERROR( @msg,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
    --drop the table
    if EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @DestinationTable)
    BEGIN
        if @RecreateIfExists = 1
            BEGIN
                exec('DROP TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + ']')
            END
        ELSE
            RETURN
    END

    SET @msg ='  CloneTable  ' + @DestinationTable + ' - Step 2, Create table. Timestamp: '  + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108)
    RAISERROR( @msg,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
    --create the table
    exec('SELECT TOP (0) * INTO [' + @DestinationTable + '] FROM [' + @SourceTable + ']')       

    --create primary key
    SET @msg ='  CloneTable  ' + @DestinationTable + ' - Step 3, Create primary key. Timestamp: '  + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108)
    RAISERROR( @msg,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
    DECLARE @PKSchema nvarchar(255), @PKName nvarchar(255),@count   INT
    SELECT TOP 1 @PKSchema = CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, @PKName = CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema AND TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    IF NOT @PKSchema IS NULL AND NOT @PKName IS NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @PKColumns nvarchar(MAX)
        SET @PKColumns = ''

        SELECT @PKColumns = @PKColumns + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],'
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
            where TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable and TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = @PKSchema AND CONSTRAINT_NAME= @PKName
            ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

        SET @PKColumns = LEFT(@PKColumns, LEN(@PKColumns) - 1)

        exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @DestinationTable + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (' + @PKColumns + ')' + @PartionScript);
    END

    --create other indexes
    SET @msg ='  CloneTable  ' + @DestinationTable + ' - Step 4, Create Indexes. Timestamp: '  + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108)
    RAISERROR( @msg,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
    DECLARE @IndexId int, @IndexName nvarchar(255), @IsUnique bit, @IsUniqueConstraint bit, @FilterDefinition nvarchar(max), @type int

    set @count=0
    DECLARE indexcursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT index_id, name, is_unique, is_unique_constraint, filter_definition, type FROM sys.indexes WHERE is_primary_key = 0 and object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']')
    OPEN indexcursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition, @type
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            set @count =@count +1
            DECLARE @Unique nvarchar(255)
            SET @Unique = CASE WHEN @IsUnique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE ' ELSE '' END

            DECLARE @KeyColumns nvarchar(max), @IncludedColumns nvarchar(max)
            SET @KeyColumns = ''
            SET @IncludedColumns = ''

            select @KeyColumns = @KeyColumns + '[' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END + ',' from sys.index_columns ic
            inner join sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
            where index_id = @IndexId and ic.object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']') and key_ordinal > 0
            order by index_column_id

            select @IncludedColumns = @IncludedColumns + '[' + c.name + '],' from sys.index_columns ic
            inner join sys.columns c ON c.object_id = ic.object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
            where index_id = @IndexId and ic.object_id = object_id('[' + @SourceSchema + '].[' + @SourceTable + ']') and key_ordinal = 0
            order by index_column_id

            IF LEN(@KeyColumns) > 0
                SET @KeyColumns = LEFT(@KeyColumns, LEN(@KeyColumns) - 1)

            IF LEN(@IncludedColumns) > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @IncludedColumns = ' INCLUDE (' + LEFT(@IncludedColumns, LEN(@IncludedColumns) - 1) + ')'
            END

            IF @FilterDefinition IS NULL
                SET @FilterDefinition = ''
            ELSE
                SET @FilterDefinition = 'WHERE ' + @FilterDefinition + ' '

            SET @msg ='  CloneTable  ' + @DestinationTable + ' - Step 4.' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5),@count) + ', Create Index ' + @IndexName + '. Timestamp: '  + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108)
            RAISERROR( @msg,0,1) WITH NOWAIT

            if @type = 2
                SET @sql = 'CREATE ' + @Unique + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] (' + @KeyColumns + ')' + @IncludedColumns + @FilterDefinition  + @PartionScript
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @sql = 'CREATE ' + @Unique + ' CLUSTERED INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [' + @DestinationSchema + '].[' + @DestinationTable + '] (' + @KeyColumns + ')' + @IncludedColumns + @FilterDefinition + @PartionScript
                END
            EXEC (@sql)
            FETCH NEXT FROM indexcursor INTO @IndexId, @IndexName, @IsUnique, @IsUniqueConstraint, @FilterDefinition, @type
       END
    CLOSE indexcursor
    DEALLOCATE indexcursor

    --create constraints
    SET @msg ='  CloneTable  ' + @DestinationTable + ' - Step 5, Create constraints. Timestamp: '  + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),108)
    RAISERROR( @msg,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
    DECLARE @ConstraintName nvarchar(max), @CheckClause nvarchar(max), @ColumnName NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE const_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
            REPLACE(dc.name, @SourceTable, @DestinationTable),[definition], c.name
        FROM sys.default_constraints dc
            INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id AND dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
        WHERE OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) =@SourceTable               
    OPEN const_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM const_cursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause, @ColumnName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            exec('ALTER TABLE [' + @DestinationTable + '] ADD CONSTRAINT [' + @ConstraintName + '] DEFAULT ' + @CheckClause + ' FOR ' + @ColumnName)
            FETCH NEXT FROM const_cursor INTO @ConstraintName, @CheckClause, @ColumnName
       END;
    CLOSE const_cursor
    DEALLOCATE const_cursor                 


END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF (SELECT CURSOR_STATUS('global','indexcursor')) >= -1
        BEGIN
         DEALLOCATE indexcursor
        END

        IF (SELECT CURSOR_STATUS('global','const_cursor')) >= -1
        BEGIN
         DEALLOCATE const_cursor
        END


        PRINT 'Error Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE(); 
    END CATCH

END

GO
```

Comment: Making this faster might be as simple as declaring your cursors as `CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD`. Personally I'm attempting to create a similar script without using cursors and see how that performs.

Comment: Hi @mendosi I know it's old, but I'm currently looking into generating CREATE script with all the misc things (constraints/indexes/partitions/triggers/etc) along with column definition. I was wondering if you had any success recreating this with a non-cursor approach. if so, would you mind sharing it? Much appreciated, thank you

Comment: The script I wrote copies one or more tables and doesn't use a cursor. It's also too big for a comment. Instead I'll link to Hans Michiels script: https://www.hansmichiels.com/2016/02/18/how-to-copy-a-database-table-structure-t-sql-scripting-series-s01e01/

Answer (score 5):

try this.. the below one copy the entire structure of the existing table but not the data.

```
create table AT_QUOTE_CART as select * from QUOTE_CART where 0=1 ;
```

if you want to copy the data then use the below one:

```
create table AT_QUOTE_CART as select * from QUOTE_CART ;
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you want to do that, but try:

```
SELECT *
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
WHERE 1 = 2
```

It should work.

Comment: I think that would also copy the data? he wants only the structure.

Answer (score 4):

1. If you Want to copy Same DataBase

   ```
   Select * INTO NewTableName from OldTableName
   ```
2. If Another DataBase

   ```
   Select * INTO NewTableName from DatabaseName.OldTableName
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable
WHERE 1 = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Copy the table structure:-
select * into newtable from oldtable where 1=2;

Copy the table structure along with table data:-
select * into newtable from oldtable where 1=1;
```

Comment: this does not copy constraints and keys

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * INTO newtable
from Oldtable
```

Comment: Please use code markup for greater readability,also that's more useful to explain a little about your code.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  In particular, it looks to the untrained eye as if this would also copy the contents of `Oldtable`.  How is that avoided?

Answer (score 3):

According to [How to Clone Tables in SQL](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-clone-tables-in-sql-dd29586ec89c), it is:

```
CREATE TABLE copyTable LIKE originalTable;
```

That works for just the sructure. For the structure and the data use this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM original_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Found here what I was looking for. Helped me recall what I used 3-4 years back.

I wanted to reuse the same syntax to be able to create table with data resulting from the join of a table.

Came up with below query after a few attempts.

```
SELECT a.*
INTO   DetailsArchive
FROM   (SELECT d.*
        FROM   details AS d
               INNER JOIN
               port AS p
               ON p.importid = d.importid
        WHERE  p.status = 2) AS a;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a table with the only structure to be copied from the original table then you can use the following command to do that.

```
create table <tablename> as select * from <sourcetablename> where 1>2;
```

By this false condition you can leave the records and copy the structure.

Comment: This is a duplicate of existing answers. Read through existing answers before submitting a new one, and add comments/votes if appropriate.

Comment: But it is not same as that of existing answer here i used create command to do this action

Comment: If you review @AbhiUrs answer (02-Jan-2015), your answer is similar to the first part of their answer, albeit with a slightly different where clause.

First part => `create table AT_QUOTE_CART as select * from QUOTE_CART where 0=1 ;`

Replace those tablenames and we get:
`create table <tablename> as select * from <sourcetablename> where 0=1 ;`

As for the where clause, `0=1` achieves the same result as `1>2` which is no data retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to copy a table from one database another database. For anyone using a GUI like Sequel Ace you can right click table and click 'copy create table syntax' and run that query (you can edit the query, e.g. change table name, remove foreign keys, add/remove columns if desired)