# Duplicating a table in dashDB

Tags: sql, dashdb

I want to create a duplicate table in dashDB (with or without the original data, it does not really matter, the table structure is what is important).

I tried:

```
SELECT * INTO new_table 
FROM old_table;
```

but I get this error:

> "new_table" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.69.56

I also tried:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
(SELECT * FROM old_table);
```

but I get this error:

> An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "AS (SELECT * FROM old_table".  Expected tokens may include:  "WITH DATA, WITH NO DATA".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.69.56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here:
[Create table (structure) from existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505728/create-table-structure-from-existing-table)

seems this did the trick

CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;

Answer (score 0):

Just do this. This will work and create an exact copy of the table including data:

CREATE TABLE NEW_TAB AS (SELECT * FROM EXISTING_TAB) WITH DATA;