# Create table (structure and data) from existing table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I want to create (and fill) a table similar to an existing table in Oracle (PL-SQL).

I used this code (extracted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505728/create-table-structure-from-existing-table)):

```
Select * into NewTable from OldTable
```

but this error occurred:

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

I think this code works only in SQL-Server. so how can I handle it in Oracle?

Comment: `select into t2 from t1` is SQL Server syntax for copying a table. In Oracle `select into` is for something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE NewTable AS
SELECT * FROM OldTable`