# Create clone copy of table without data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I create clone copy of table without data? Because I just want to copy a definition of table not data.

I tried below but it is copying data as well

```
Select * 
into Clone_Supplier  
from Supplier
```

Comment: I'm seeing you already accepted an answer. Your question doesn't make it clear whether you want the whole definition of the table, including constraints (primary key, defaults, foreign keys, checks, ...), indexes, triggers on the table, and so on. Note that the answer you accepted will not create any constraints, won't have any indexes and won't have any of the triggers that applied to the original table.

Comment: This looks like a duplication to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2505728/9294131
Select Top 0 * into NewTable from OldTable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create table (structure) from existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505728/create-table-structure-from-existing-table)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Copy all columns from selected table

```
Select Top 0 * into NewTable from OldTable
```

Copy some columns from selected table

```
Select Top 0 Col1,Col2 into NewTable from OldTable
```

Copy all(Data and Structure)

```
Select * into NewTable from OldTable
```

Comment: how can I clone only with structure?

Comment: You can Try this to clone with structure.  

CREATE TABLE NewTable
AS (SELECT * FROM OldTable WHERE 1=2);

Comment: No, it's not working : CREATE TABLE [test].[dbo].[users] AS (SELECT * FROM [store_dev].[dbo].[users] WHERE 1=2);

Comment: If previous one does not  work 
then please try this hope this will work. Thanks
Select * into NewTable from OldTable WHERE 1=2

Comment: but it does not copy the entire structure of a database with indexes and constraints, I already tried that anyways I resolved that problem. Ref: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244973/how-can-i-clone-a-database-in-microsoft-sql-server-using-php/245206?noredirect=1#comment484224_245206

Comment: I love a good, simple solution using plain SQL that I never would have thought of. I did not realize "TOP 0" would be valid, but this is the perfect use case for it. Gonna save me a ton of time, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You could add `WHERE 1=2` to get structure only:

```
Select * 
into Clone_Supplier 
from Supplier
where 1=2;
```

It won't be exact copy though:

- no constraints
- no indexes
- no triggers

Comment: What should i do to copy indexes and identity?

Comment: @SqlLearner You could use [Generate script in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429902/generate-script-in-sql-server-management-studio) and then rename table and dependencies with new name.

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO` *does* copy `IDENTITY`

Comment: @MartinSmith I stand corrected :) I am not sure why I was thinking about `IDENTITY(int,1,1)` like in **[DEMO](http://rextester.com/QWWO37333)**

Answer (score 4):

It is useful table to generate and new table

```
 Select Top 0 * into tblNew from tblOld
```

Comment: Ohh this one is very useful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution Query :**

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO newTable1 FROM oldTable1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add one false condition. So that it wont return any data and you will create clone copy of table without data. you can use below query

```
Select * into Clone_Supplier from Supplier WHERE 1=2
```

Answer (score -1):

Create Table new_table LIKE old_table

Will create an empty copy of original table with original attributes etc.

Comment: Select Top 0 * into NewTable from OldTable