# create table (structure) from query (MS-Access)

Tags: ms-access

I like to create an empty table from a (pivot) query in Microsoft Access (using Office 365 1902). With the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505728/create-table-structure-from-existing-table) I found a solution with one shortcoming:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * INTO tblNew FROM qryMyQuery;
```

The shortcoming is that `tblNew` contains one record which needs to be deleted to get an empty table. Access 365 can not process `SELECT TOP 0 * INTO`.

I post this primarily because other people may have the same question and run into the same problem. I can work with my solution, but maybe somebody has a better one?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple:

```
SELECT * INTO tblNew FROM qryMyQuery WHERE False;
```

Since the `WHERE` condition matches 0 rows, 0 rows get copied.