# Visual Studio creating access table SQL

Tags: c#, sql

My goal is to create new tables in a access file by copying the format of a existing table named "TIME_LOG".  I keep getting a syntax error, i believe i am doing something wrong in my query1 variable.

```
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath;
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        connect.Open();
        string query1 = "create table " + textBox1.Text + " SELECT TIME, FROM TIME_LOG";
        MessageBox.Show(query1); 

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query1, connect);
        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = query1;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connect.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the guidelines for creating new tables in access, here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql

It is possible to do it in SQL server, but I don't know if access supports it.
sample in sql:
[Create table (structure) from existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505728/create-table-structure-from-existing-table)