# Why Foo, Bar and Baz?

Tags: coding-style, identifier, naming-conventions, metasyntactic-variable

Just by mere curiosity and without any goal in life... I was wondering what is the origin and the meaning (if there is any) of "foo", "bar" and "baz" as generic identifiers used in many programming examples?

Comment: You may like to read these sources: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/4868904/1267304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868904/what-is-the-origin-of-foo-and-bar) [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar)