# Mysql SELECT , find number of rows , then INSERT in a single query statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Let say we have inbox table and only maximum 50 messages can be recieved at a time, I use the following code for this purpose:

```
$maximum_messages_in_inbox = 50;

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from inbox");
if(mysql_num_rows($query1) > $maximum_messages_in_inbox)
{
   echo "Message memmory if full please try again later";
}
else
{
   mysql_query("insert into inbox set text = '$text' , sender = '$sender' ");
}
```

This code work very well, but each time two queries will be executed.

My question is can we adjust above purpose in a single query like:

```
mysql_query("select * from inbox if num > 50 insert else error");
if(error)
{
   echo "Message memmory if full please try again later";
}
```

Looking forward to your co-operation. Thanks

Comment: [Don't use mysql_* anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Just as an FYI, you are using deprecated `mysql_` functions, which can cause the risk of sql injection.  You might want to look into `mysqli_` or `PDO` for safety purposes

Comment: Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: dear i m using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` but just for asking purpose i use mysql, anyhow thanks for suggestion . i will use `mysqli` for asking next time

Comment: But @JayBlanchard I think i is hard really :(

Comment: @Sajad go look at the link in my comment. It really simplifies PDO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i have a question, do you know what is `foo` ?  Is it dummy name of what ? tnx

Comment: [`'foo'`](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3092.txt) is a dummy variable @Sajad

Comment: aha i see, then `foo` and `$var` are the same, right ?

Comment: It certainly could be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do conditional `INSERT` in SQL with this trick :

```
INSERT INTO inbox(text, sender)
SELECT 'text value', 'sender value'
FROM dual
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inbox) < 50;
```

Thay way the `INSERT` will be processed only if the `WHERE` clause is satisfied.

Comment: thanks, i'm trying it but please tell me you used `dual` word in `mysql_query`, it is `table_name` or `keyword` @vard

Comment: `dual` is a dummy table name. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html
So you don't need to create a table named `dual`

Comment: I always like to know what is `foo`? is it dummy name of what ?

Comment: thank u so much @vard , i tried it and it work very well, at start i use same table name instead of `dual` then i face a new problem but then i tried `dual` and it work very well, my problem solved thank u so much

Comment: @Sajad Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868904/what-is-the-origin-of-foo-and-bar ;)