# what does "foo" and "bar" mean and why people like use them as example case?

Tags: http, go, memcached

In many program test case or example case, i always see "bar" and "foo", what is the two word represent for and why choose this two words as example?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Foobar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar).

Comment: Based on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) these are variables whose name is not important... This question could be considered out of topic, but is definitely programming related and a good one :) (every beginner wonders at some point)

Comment: They are called *metasyntactic variables*. The etymology of `foo` and `bar` are uncertain. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google can answer your question far better than I. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar#History_and_etymology):

> The word foo originated as a nonsense word from the 1930s, the military term FUBAR emerged in the 1940s, and the use of foo in a programming context is generally credited to the Tech Model Railroad Club (TMRC) of MIT from circa 1960.[9] However, the precise relationship of these terms is not known with certainty, and several anecdotal theories have been advanced to identify them.

Also, have a look at this question: [What is the origin of foo and bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868904/what-is-the-origin-of-foo-and-bar) as well as this one: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/69788/what-is-the-history-of-the-use-of-foo-and-bar-in-source-code-examples